# Native android smartapp from SmartThings

Tags: android, native, smartthings

I would like to create a native Android app to control my devices with SmartThings.

Do you know if it is possible or is it just possible to code a groovy app as they say in their **`API`** doc?

[Here is the Link](http://docs.smartthings.com/en/latest/getting-started/groovy-basics.html#groovy-basics)

Answer (score 0):

The groovy apps that you referenced is for creating apps that are executed on SmartThings servers. This is a specific Groovy DSL that is proprietary to SmartThings.

If you would like to create a native app you would need to use their API, and control your devices through HTTP requests. I'm not sure how much of the API is public and might require some reverse engineering.